Spring jpa does .saveAll(items) returns the items in the same order as in arguments?
I have an entity of name Items. I have another entity mapping which maps these items to customer.
I have a function which takes a list of items:
I want to do items = itemsRepository.saveAll(items)
Then after getting the id I want to iterate and map them.
I want to know whether .saveAll returns items in the same order as they have been in the arguments

Why is the same order important? You should always do the mapping with key rather than order.

In the latest spring-data-jpa:3.3.2 you can see the implementation of saveAll from CrudRepository is implemented by SimpleJpaRepository would save and return them in the same order:
@Override
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {

    Assert.notNull(entities, "Entities must not be null");

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}

You can find implementation code here

The documentation makes no guarantees about the order of returned iterable:

Returns:
the saved entities; will never be null. The returned Iterable will have the same size as the Iterable passed as an argument.

ListCrudRepository, which redefines the method to return a List, makes no guarantees either.
The current implementation will return a list in the same order, but this is an implementation detail and you should not rely on it. This may change at any time and this may break your code, if you rely on the order of returned list.
Keep in mind that the method argument (input) is an Iterable, it may be any data structure, even an unordered one (hash set, for example), making it even less reliable.
